# With FPPopoverController every time I exit the view with the popover, it NSLogs "FPPopover dealloc", how can I stop this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fppopover

It seems in the file: https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover/blob/master/FPPopoverController.m#L89

At that line it says if the debug option is set to announce it. I don't want it set, nor do I remember setting it. If that's the reason, how do I unset debug? If it's not, how do I make it stop saying that.

Comment: Comment out the unwanted log message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach to avoiding the NSLog message is to simply comment it out.

As to your question either some header file or the compilation command is defining FP_DEBUG.  Search the header files, find FP_DEBUG and unset it (comment it out or use `#undef`).  If it isn't in a header file, look at the targets build settings (select the target, click 'build settings', search for FP_DEBUG.  If you find it, like in 'Other C Flags', remove it.

Comment: I cmd-f'd FP_DEBUG in every FP file, to no avail as far as finding a setting goes. And in target build settings I searched for it as well, to no avail.

Comment: Found it. Was in FPPopoverController.m, right above it. Doh. Edit: And ARCMacros.h